# Sharepoint access from outlook problems

Tags: outlook, accessibility

I have just set up sharepoint 2010 server where i work. In this server i have many calendars wich are connected to my outlook and i share these calendars to other people working here. But even tough i have given all these users access to bot my calendar in outlook and on the sharepoint server they are not able to insert new items and view others. There may simply be some access rights i have forgotten but i cant seem to find them.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you running?

Comment: I´m using outlook 2007